# Where is Microsoft.Xbox.WinJS.1.0? Cannot resolve PackageDependency in package.appxmanifest

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp, winjs, xbox-one

I am attempting to upgrade a Windows 8 WinRT JS app that was made for Windows 8, to Universal Windows Platform (Windodws 10).

I've made necessary project / manifest changes, and have the project building, but on deployment attempt, it complains

> this package depends on a framework that could not be found. Provide the framework "Microsoft.Xbox.WinJS.1.0"

I've attempted to drop in the latest WinJS (4.4), but the app uses javascript code from that package.

That package is nowhere to be found on the web.  Is it part of the Xbox XDK?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> this package depends on a framework that could not be found. Provide the framework "Microsoft.Xbox.WinJS.1.0"

"Microsoft.Xbox.WinJS.1.0" is part of WinJS 2.0 release. See [WinJS 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinJS#WinJS_2.0). But now it's not available on the Internet anymore. A lot of changes has been made for the latest release.

So it is not recommended using WinJS 2.0 in a UWP(Html/JS) App. (Some of the APIs could be not available anymore in the UWP platform). You might need to change those related codes to suit for the WinJS 4.x.